# changing class variables python

Tags: python, oop

I am writing a script to read DXF files and return length and area of the shapes so that I can automatically calculate the price of laser cut parts.

Arc should take arc name, center point, radius, starting angle, ending angle from the dxf file.
Arc should calculate the starting and ending point of the arc.

The problem is, that the angles are arbitrary so the starting and ending point are arbitrary, 
And such it is hard for me to string arcs together to form a full figure, 
I need a mechanism to switch the starting and ending point if I notice that it’s backwards.
I tried to write a function in arc class, to switch the starting and ending points
But it isn’t working, 
I am not so strong with OOP, please help

attached code

```
    class arc:
       def __init__(self, name, center_point, radius, angles):
    self.name = name
    self.center_point = center_point
    self.radius = radius
    self.starting_angle = angles[0]
    self.ending_angle = angles[1]

    starting_angle = angles[0]
    ending_angle = angles[1]
    self.starting_point = center_point[0]+radius * math.cos((starting_angle)*((math.pi)/(180))),center_point[1]+radius * math.sin((starting_angle)*((math.pi)/(180)))
    self.ending_point = center_point[0]+radius * math.cos((ending_angle)*((math.pi)/(180))),center_point[1]+radius * math.sin((ending_angle)*((math.pi)/(180)))

    starting_point =center_point[0]+radius * math.cos((starting_angle)*((math.pi)/(180))),center_point[1]+radius * math.sin((starting_angle)*((math.pi)/(180)))
    ending_point = center_point[0]+radius * math.cos((ending_angle)*((math.pi)/(180))),center_point[1]+radius * math.sin((ending_angle)*((math.pi)/(180)))
    self.length = math.sqrt((starting_point[0]-ending_point[0])**2+(starting_point[1]-ending_point[1])**2)
```

I desire a function called switch

this is how it should work:

```
    arc1.starting_point = (0,0)
    arc1.ending_point = (1,1)
    print(arc1.starting_point, arc1.ending_point)
    #Desired Output:
    ((0,0),(1,1))

    arc1.switch()
    print(arc1.starting_point, arc1.ending_point)

    #Desired Output:
    ((1,1),(0,0))
```

Comment: In my opinion, you can put these data in a list and use reverse function

Comment: Why are you duplicating your point calculations?

Comment: will be debugged, this is still work in progress

Comment: tried reversing a list, 
it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the values of two variables with simultaneous assignment:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> y = 1
>>> x, y = y, x
>>> x
1
>>> y
0
```

so

```
def switch(self):
    self.starting_point, self.ending_point = self.ending_point, self.starting_point
```

should do it.

Comment: I tried it, 
the switch function doesn't permanently change the variable, after switching the instance variables stay the same